# Android: How to convert 'view' to 'textview'?

Tags: android, view, textview, onlongclicklistener

I have a number of `TextView`s that each share a single `OnLongClickListener`

Within the `onLongClick` event, I want to identify which `TextView` triggered the event.

However, the event is defined as:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View view)
```

I tried casting `view` to `TextView`, but that didn't work.

How can I get at the widget that triggered the `OnLongClick` event?

Comment: How did casting `view` to `TextView` not work? Did you try checking `if (view instanceof TextView)` first to make sure it wasn't triggered from the wrong view?

Comment: I tried casting view to TextView, but that didn't work. .......... are you getting any error ,pls share error log . else share code of onLongClick()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `View` should be your TextView.

Try something like this:

```
if( view instanceof TextView ) {
  TextView textView = (TextView) view;
  //Do your stuff
}
```

To verify that the above if-statement is valid you can try running it like this first:

```
if( view instanceof TextView ) {
  Log.e( "MyTag", "It's a TextView!" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use view.getId() method to get id of clicked view.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.first_text_view: // do things here; break;
                ...
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` **is Already** a `View`, All Widgets Are extending from `View`, so all what you need is a switch on the `id` of your TextViews like this :

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.txt1: // your code for the textView which have the id R.id.txt1  ...;
                     break;
            case R.id.txt2: // your code for the textView which have the id R.id.txt2  ...; 
                    break;
                //... etc
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the error you are getting ? normally this should work. If you set the `yourTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this)`, and then `public boolean onLongClick(View view)` will trigger and you don't need to cast it.